# sort messages by date divider

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building a chat based on jquery and firestore, and i managed to make retrieve the messages onSnapshot ordered by date, but now am trying to add a date divider by day, so when user open the chat he will find a divider for each day and under each divider the messages happens on this day.

this is my code:

```
firestore.collection("chat").orderBy("date","desc").limit(10).onSnapshot(function(snapshot) {       

            $(".messages").html('');

            var curUser = '';
            var curDate = '';
            var curDay = '';
            snapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                console.log("djsidjsdoisjdis");
                 $(".chat-content").animate({ scrollTop: $('.chat-content').prop("scrollHeight")}, 100); 

               if(curDate!== doc.data().date.toLocaleDateString()){
                   curDate=doc.data().date.toLocaleDateString();
                   $(".messages").append('<h1>'+doc.data().date.toLocaleDateString()+'</h1>');  
                   }

                if(doc.data().user_name != username){
                    // My message

                    if(doc.data().user_name !== curUser) {
                        // SHOW USER NAME
                        curUser = doc.data().user_name;
                        $(".messages").append('<ul class="message message-received message-appear-from-bottom message-appeared message-first message-last message-with-tail"><li class="message-name">'+doc.data().user_name+'</li><li id="message-date" class="hide">'+doc.data().date+'</li><li class="message-text">'+doc.data().message+'</li></ul>');
                    } else {
                        // SHOW MESSAGE WITHOUT USERNAME
                        $(".messages").append('<ul class="message message-received message-appear-from-bottom message-appeared message-first message-last message-with-tail"><li id="message-date" class="hide">'+doc.data().date+'</li><li class="message-text">'+doc.data().message+'</li></ul>');
                    }
                } else {
                    // other users messages
                    if(doc.data().user_name !== curUser) {
                        // Show messsgae with user name:
                        curUser = doc.data().user_name;
                        $(".messages").append('<ul class="message message-sent message-first message-last message-with-tail message-appear-from-bottom message-appeared"><li id="message-date" class="hide">'+doc.data().date+'</li><li class="message-name">'+doc.data().user_name+'</li><li class="message-text">'+doc.data().message+'</li></ul>');
                    } else {
                        // Show message without user name:
                        $(".messages").append('<ul class="message message-sent message-first message-last message-with-tail message-appear-from-bottom message-appeared"><li id="message-date" class="hide">'+doc.data().date+'</li><li class="message-text">'+doc.data().message+'</li></ul>');

                    }
                }


            });
            var list = $('.messages');
                var listItems = list.children('ul.message');
                list.append(listItems.get().reverse());

        });
```

Here is a screenshot from what i get, i got the date dividers after each others not seperating the messages.
[chat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nZ49.png)

Comment: can you share excerpt of your json .. in your case `snapshot`

Comment: @KresimirPendic I didn't include the json in this function, the usernames are defined as static variables for now. as i just want to sort the messages from firestore under divider dates

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with this code:

```
var list = $('.messages');
var listItems = list.children('ul.message');
list.append(listItems.get().reverse());
```

This code takes only the UL elements from the `.messages` , sort them in reverse and append to the end of your list, keeping the date H1 headers on top of the list.

If you want to sort the date groups in reverse and also the chat messages in each group,  you need to slightly change your markup to wrap the date group, and first reverse sort the date groups and then each group's messages. Your markup & code should be like this:

```js
 
var list = $('.messages');
var listItems = list.children('.dategroup');
list.append(listItems.get().reverse());

$('.dategroup').each(function(){
   var ullist = $(this).children('ul.message')
   $(this).append(ullist.get().reverse());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="messages">
    <div class="dategroup">
       <h1>DATE 1</h1>
       <ul class="message message-sent message-first message-last message-with-tail message-appear-from-bottom message-appeared"><li>chatitem 1 </li></ul> 
       <ul class="message message-sent message-first message-last message-with-tail message-appear-from-bottom message-appeared"><li>chatitem 2</li></ul> 
    </div>
    <div class="dategroup">
       <h1>DATE 2</h1>
       <ul class="message message-sent message-first message-last message-with-tail message-appear-from-bottom message-appeared"><li>chatitem 3</li></ul> 
       <ul class="message message-sent message-first message-last message-with-tail message-appear-from-bottom message-appeared"><li>chatitem 4</li></ul> 
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

To apply this example to your code:

```
    firestore.collection("chat").orderBy("date","desc").limit(10).onSnapshot(function(snapshot) {       

        $(".messages").html('');

        var curUser = '';
        var curDate = '';
        var curDay = '';
        snapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            console.log("djsidjsdoisjdis");
             $(".chat-content").animate({ scrollTop: $('.chat-content').prop("scrollHeight")}, 100); 

           if(curDate!== doc.data().date.toLocaleDateString()){
               curDate=doc.data().date.toLocaleDateString();
               var $dateGroup = $("<div class='dategroup'></div>")
               $('.messages').append($dateGroup)
               $dateGroup.append('<h1>'+doc.data().date.toLocaleDateString()+'</h1>');  
           }

            if(doc.data().user_name != username){
                // My message

                if(doc.data().user_name !== curUser) {
                    // SHOW USER NAME
                    curUser = doc.data().user_name;
                    $dateGroup.append('<ul class="message message-received message-appear-from-bottom message-appeared message-first message-last message-with-tail"><li class="message-name">'+doc.data().user_name+'</li><li id="message-date" class="hide">'+doc.data().date+'</li><li class="message-text">'+doc.data().message+'</li></ul>');
                } else {
                    // SHOW MESSAGE WITHOUT USERNAME
                    $dateGroup.append('<ul class="message message-received message-appear-from-bottom message-appeared message-first message-last message-with-tail"><li id="message-date" class="hide">'+doc.data().date+'</li><li class="message-text">'+doc.data().message+'</li></ul>');
                }
            } else {
                // other users messages
                if(doc.data().user_name !== curUser) {
                    // Show messsgae with user name:
                    curUser = doc.data().user_name;
                    $dateGroup.append('<ul class="message message-sent message-first message-last message-with-tail message-appear-from-bottom message-appeared"><li id="message-date" class="hide">'+doc.data().date+'</li><li class="message-name">'+doc.data().user_name+'</li><li class="message-text">'+doc.data().message+'</li></ul>');
                } else {
                    // Show message without user name:
                    $dateGroup.append('<ul class="message message-sent message-first message-last message-with-tail message-appear-from-bottom message-appeared"><li id="message-date" class="hide">'+doc.data().date+'</li><li class="message-text">'+doc.data().message+'</li></ul>');

                }
            }


        });
        var list = $('.messages');
        var listItems = list.children('.dategroup');
        list.append(listItems.get().reverse());

        $('.dategroup').each(function(){
           var ullist = $(this).children('ul.message')
           $(this).append(ullist.get().reverse());
       })

    });
```

Comment: but that will add the date on each message, no checking for the current date, i want the date to be shown only if it's different from the current date, like new day!

Comment: It was an example of how to sort the markup. See my edit on how to apply the example to your code - and no, it displays the date only once